# What is the best way of testing XML responses?

Tags: xml, testing, selenium, response

I'm using selenium IDE to test my webpages but unfortunately I cannot use it to test those pages that return an xml response. Some people use Selenium Remote Control, others use Pearl modules like WWW::Mechanize and Test::XML or Test::XPath (but these are no option for me since I use Java).

What is the best way to test the XML responses?

Comment: What's the downside using selenium rc? Should work fine I think. Use XPath expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to compare the response against an expected value. If direct comparison isn't desirable, you can filter the response first, e.g. an XSLT transform, to produce something that is more easily tested.